# Flask-SQLAlchemy: relationship querying and nested object data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am playing at python RESTful-API with Flask-SQLAlchemy I got struct at querying 1-M relationship between 2 Table, like *Location(1) may have many Buildings(m)*
This is what I did (my project structure):

```
project 
     model
         __init__.py
         location.py
         building.py
    resource     
         __init__.py
         location.py
         building.py
    schema
         __init__.py
         schema.py     
     app.py
     database.py
```

This is my model:

```
class Building(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'building'
    building_code = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True)
    building_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    building_type = db.Column(db.String(80))
    location_code = db.Column(db.Integer, 
    db.ForeignKey("location.location_code"), nullable=False)
    locations = db.relationship("Location", back_populates="buildings", 
    lazy='joined')
      
class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'location'
    location_code = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    location_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    latitude = db.Column(db.String(80))
    longitude = db.Column(db.String(80))
    buildings = db.relationship("Building", back_populates="locations", 
    lazy='joined')
```

This is my resource:

```
class BuildingList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        buildings = buildingModel.query.all()
        results = buildings_schema.dump(buildings)
        print(results)

class LocationList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        locations = locationModel.query.all()
        results = locations_schema.dump(locations)
        print(results)
```

When I try to "GET" `/BuildingList`, there is no error but, not complete in `Location()` model. this is what I got  "location_code": [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
**It entirely NULL**

I am trying and looking for the result as Nested Object like `Building{building_code:"X",building_name:"Y",building_type:"Z",location_code:{LocationModel}}` for example.
I try to print `buildingModel.query` - It is already SQL joined command I think the problem is in mapping object as my understanding, may I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To query a database you must first create an object of its class definition in your Flask code.

From your code, the `class Building` and the `class Location`  should be queried. So it should be like:

```
class BuildingList(Resource):
def get(self):
    buildings = Building.query.all()
    results = buildings_schema.dump(buildings)
    print(results)

class LocationList(Resource):
def get(self):
    locations = Location.query.all()
    results = locations_schema.dump(locations)
    print(results)
```

I don't see any definition for `buildingModel` or `locationModel` in your code.

Comment: Thank, oh I forgot to tell you. Yes I did it already with  locationModel =  Location() and buildingModel = Building().

Comment: I also do not see your Flask routes. If you have enabled Flask Debugging, you will get debug messages in your console. Please add those messages too.